# How to put an image on JPanel netbeans?

Tags: image, netbeans, jpanel

I know this has probably been ask one billion times, but I am still finding it difficult in getting a straight forward answer.

Where do you put the code under? Can you just add it through the GUI builder-if so how? Or do you have to 'manually' add it in the code? If so do you put it under public class or just class? How to you write it?

Comment: Did my answer help you at all??

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it....But Im no java programmer ;)

First I initiate the variable,

```
 private javax.swing.JLabel myImage; //notice its a jLabel
```

Then in initcomponents();

I set the icon I want...

```
 myImage.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png")));
```

Then once Ive initiated my jPanel....its just an addComponent, to set it....

```
    .addComponent(myImage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 383, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
```

But yes you can do it through the GUI builder...

To do that, just drag a JLabel, into your panel....

Then in the side, in the Properties, youll see a field called 'icon', then just browse for your image, and voila!  Its that simple!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, the 2nd line is underlined red aka myImage.setIcon(new etc." and when I attempt to do it through GUI builder, the "icon" is not there when I have press or 'highlight' the JPanel, though it is there when I press or 'highlight' a button on the GUI

Comment: my version of netbeans is 6.9.1

Comment: Your example was for a JLabel, I was able to add the picture I wanted to the GUI, only I'm unsure (or if it's even possible) how to move it too the back so all the text overlaps it. Any idea?